# sink_csv memory management issue while running multiple processes simultaneously

Tags: python, python-polars

I ran into memory issues while working with polars' sink_csv. I was running multiple processes (61 in total) simultaneously on a fairly large machine with 400 GB of RAM. During the processes that was handling the `sink_csv` tasks it resulted in a memory overflow. From my understanding the `sink_csv` should be used in a single process and it can handle the memory limits well there. However, in my case this is not feasible as it is running on multiple cores with multiple processes and that part of the code is out of my reach. Is there a solution for sink_`csv` to be aware of other processes' memory usage? Is there an option that can limit `sink_csv`'s memory usage? What would be an optimal implementation for this issue?

Before using `sink_csv` I concat `LazyFrames` together and apply aggregation methods (sum, mean, min, max) on columns.

This is the memory usage of the given run:

[image: This is the memory usage of the given run]

Each line represents a process that was responsible for a calculation and the dark blue lines at the end are the ones where calling `sink_csv` occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [open feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9892) that is [worked on](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11153) at the moment.

I'll provide an update here as soon as the feature is officially released.